# Delete Temporary File with FileStreamResult

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, download

I am using MVC3 to return a temporary file that is created in code. Then, I use `FileStreamResult` to stream this file back to the client. However, as this is a temporary file that I no longer need, I would like to clean up the file. I don't know how to do this since I am already hitting the return statement while streaming. Thanks.

```
public FileStreamResult Download()
{
    string filename = Path.GetTempFileName();
    using (FileStream stream = new FileStream(filename, FileMode.OpenOrCreate))
    {
        CreateFile(this.DataContext, stream);
    }

    using (FileStream outputStream = new FileStream(filename, FileMode.Open))
    {
        HttpContext.Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=MyFile.xlsx");
        return new FileStreamResult(outputStream,MimeTypeUtil.GetMimeType("xlsx"));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may not actually need a temporary file if your code is like what you posted.  (This assumes your method is inside of a `Controller`):

```
public ActionResult Download()
{
    using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        CreateFile(this.DataContext, stream);
        stream.Position = 0; // Not sure if this is necessary
        return File(stream, MimeTypeUtil.GetMimeType("xlsx"), "MyFile.xlsx");
    }
}
```

`FileStreamResult` is sort of a misnomer.  It appears to accept any `Stream` object, not just file streams.

Answer (score 4):

Seems like exact fit for creating custom [ResultFilter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.iresultfilter.aspx). You could directly subclass `ActionFilterAttribute`. Something along these lines (*missing part of file name detection*)

```
public class ResultFilter : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnResultExecuted(ResultExecutedContext filterContext)
    {
        string fileName = //((FileStreamResult)filterContext.Result). ???

        File.Delete(fileName);
    }
}
```

You could create custom ActionResult by subclassing `FileStreamResult` to pass along temp file name. Then the deletion would be trivial.